# Best way to create sleeve attaching plastic to metal?

Tags: adhesive, load-bearing

I have a parasol whose umbrella is connected to the stand using just one screw, which goes through the plastic mould on one side, right the way through the metal pole, and out of the pole and sleeve on the other:

[image: Screw head]

[image: Screw end]

This is a bit weak because it puts a lot of stress on the plastic mould every time the parasol is turned.  I'd like to attach the mould permanently to the metal pole using some kind of "sleeve" that attaches all the way around.  What's the best material for me to use to do this?  I could try sturdy duct tape, perhaps, but that seems like a bit of a tacky solution and the tape's adhesive could still slip.  Is there anything better that would be more durable?

Comment: Furniture modification that's not woodworking is somewhat outside the scope of this site.

Comment: I'd be willing to bet that there's more engagement between the two parts that just the screw. It's probably slotted or keyed. The screw just helps keep it together. It also strikes me as odd that the threads are exposed. Is there a cap missing?

Comment: @isherwood so the tube is metal and the attachment is plastic, so where does the woodworking come in to it? Or are you suggesting to make a new wood replacement for the plastic?

Comment: That was an odd interpretation. :) I'm saying your question is off topic. If it dealt with woodworking [it would be an exception](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/753/furniture-repair-off-topic).

Comment: If you're really concerned I'd put four more sheet metal screws through the coupling to spread load. As long as you don't overtighten that should provide lots of support.

Comment: Usually that type of screw attachment is just to keep two parts together, like when you pick up one piece by hand, not to mount/lock two parts mechanically together.  In the first picture the screw was maybe tighten too much, stress marks in the plastic.

Comment: @isherwood How do you mean, you mean actually drill more holes through the metal to get the extra screws through?

Comment: Sheet metal screws are generally short and self-drilling or self-tapping. Just run a few in.

Comment: Surely this pole is thicker than sheet metal.  Probably wouldn't go through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make a metal (aluminium probably) collar with a slit to allow fitting that can be glued to the plastic and riveted to the metal.